# Insert child into JTree TreeNode and update the view

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I got the following code [reduced to minimum]:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static String StrBenutzer;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    TreeNode TreeNodeRoot = createInitTree();
    JTree tree = new JTree(TreeNodeRoot);


    static DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeRoot;
    static DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeProjekte;
    static DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeAllgemein;



    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void initWindow() {



        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
                    frame.setUndecorated(false);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MainWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1160, 679);


        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        SpringLayout sl_contentPane = new SpringLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(sl_contentPane);



        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, tree, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        tree.setEditable(true);
        contentPane.add(tree);

        JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, tree, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, btnAdd);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, tree, -11, SpringLayout.NORTH, btnAdd);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnAdd, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, contentPane);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, btnAdd, -10, SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
        contentPane.add(btnAdd);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnDelete, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, btnAdd);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnDelete, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, btnAdd);
        contentPane.add(btnDelete);

        JButton btnInfo = new JButton("Info");
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, tree, 1, SpringLayout.EAST, btnInfo);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, btnInfo, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, btnAdd);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, btnInfo, 6, SpringLayout.EAST, btnDelete);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, btnInfo, 59, SpringLayout.EAST, btnDelete);
        contentPane.add(btnInfo);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, tree);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panel, 16, SpringLayout.EAST, tree);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel, 565, SpringLayout.NORTH, contentPane);
        sl_contentPane.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panel, 39, SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
        contentPane.add(panel);
    }




    private static TreeNode createInitTree(){


        NodeRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("User");
        NodeProjekte = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "Projekte");
        NodeAllgemein = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( "Allgemein" );

        DefaultMutableTreeNode projectA = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projekt A");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode projectB = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Projekt B");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode LinkProjectA = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Öffnen");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode LinkProjektB = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Öffnen");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode NotizProjektA = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Notiz");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode NoitzProjektB = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Notiz");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode Zeitstrahl = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Zeitplan");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode ToDo = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("ToDo");

        NodeProjekte.add( projectA );
        NodeProjekte.add( projectB );

        projectA.add(LinkProjectA);
        projectA.add(NotizProjektA);

        projectB.add(LinkProjektB);
        projectB.add(NoitzProjektB);

        NodeAllgemein.add(Zeitstrahl);
        NodeAllgemein.add(ToDo);

        NodeRoot.add( NodeProjekte );
        NodeRoot.add( NodeAllgemein );

        return NodeRoot;
    }




    private static void addItem(String StrProjektLink, String StrProjektName){

        DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeNewProject = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(StrProjektName);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeNewProjectLink = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Link");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode NodeNewProjectNotiz = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Notiz");

        NodeProjekte.add(NodeNewProject);
        NodeNewProject.add(NodeNewProjectLink);
        NodeNewProject.add(NodeNewProjectNotiz);






    }


    private static void deleteItem(){

    }

    private static void updateTree(){


    }




    private void addProjectFolder()
    {

    addItem("C:/Users/", "User-Directory"a);

    }




}
```

Now I want to update the JTree model, after adding or removing a child from the Tree. But Eclipse said, that all my variables and functions have to be static, so I cant't update the elements. Whats the easiest way to update the JTree?

Comment: `"Eclipse said, that all my variables and functions have to be static"` -- no, Java (not Eclipse -- Java) is not saying exactly that. Re-read the error message, and then try to fix it the other way. Instead of making most of your fields and methods static, make them instance (except the main method of course), and only try to access them in a non-static way. That you're having this problem suggests that you've got a gap in in your foundational knowledge of Java and need to fill this gap before trying to strive ahead with GUI programming.

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for a working example. The `TreeDemo` example will show you how to structure your code so your don't need static variables or methods. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all the Swing basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks to have nothing to do with Swing or JTree, and all to do with use and abuse of static vs. instance fields and methods. The best solution in my mind is to make all your fields private instance fields, and all your methods above instance methods, except perhaps your `initWindow()` method. Then the solution will fall out.

```
// !! make everything private and nothing static
// also follow Java naming conventions
private TreeNode treeNodeRoot = createInitTree();
private JTree tree = new JTree(treeNodeRoot);
private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeRoot;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeProjekte;
private DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeAllgemein;


private class AddAction implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String message = "Enter node name:";
        String nodeName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(MainWindow.this, message);

        // ...

        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = null;
        TreePath parentPath = tree.getSelectionPath();

        // ....

        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeName);
        int index = parentNode.getChildCount();
        DefaultTreeModel treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parentNode, index);
    }
}
```